# Cómo calcular la distancia de seguridad?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Necesito ayuda, no sé que hago mal. En el segundo `if tipocalzada =="mojada"` al ejecutarlo, necesito que se multiplique x2, pero no sé porqué no me lo ejecuta.
Si la calzada está mojada, en este caso la distancia a dejar tendría que ser el doble que en las calzadas secas.

```
<script>
    function pulsa() {
        var valor = parseInt(num.value);
        var distancia = parseInt(valor / 10);
        distancia = distancia * distancia;
        var tipocalzada = calzada.value;
        var tipovia = via.value;
        var tipovehiculo = vehiculo.value;

        if (tipocalzada == "seca") {
            distancia = distancia;
        }

        if (tipocalzada == "mojada") {
            distancia = distancia * 2;
        }

        if (tipovehiculo == "pesado" && tipovia != "poblado" && distancia < 50) {
            distancia = (50);
        }

        if (tipovehiculo == "pesado" && tipovia == "tunel" && distancia < 150) {
            distancia = 150;
        }

        if (distancia < 100 && tipovia == "tunel" && tipovehiculo != "pesado") {
            distancia = 100;
        }



        capa.innerHTML = "Distancia mínima: " + distancia + " m.<br> Tipo de calzada: " + tipocalzada + "<br> Con un vehículo: " + tipovehiculo + "<br> Tipo de vía: " + tipovia;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Pon con `debugger` o un `console.log(tipocalzada)` antes de ese `if` para ver qué valor tiene.

Comment: que pasa si el tipo de calzada es mojada y el tipo vehículo pesado?

Comment: Tenes un lío con las condiciones, fijate bien los criterios, y usa `if(){}else{}`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un cierto lío con las condiciones, ejecuta primero las que dependen del tipo de vehiculo, tipo de vía y distancia con if/else if/else y después duplica la distancia con otro if

```
<script>
    function pulsa() {
        var valor = parseInt(num.value);
        var distancia = parseInt(valor / 10);
        distancia = distancia * distancia;
        var tipocalzada = calzada.value;
        var tipovia = via.value;
        var tipovehiculo = vehiculo.value;

        if (tipovehiculo == "pesado" && tipovia != "poblado" && distancia < 50) {
            distancia = 50;
        }
        else if (tipovehiculo == "pesado" && tipovia == "tunel" && distancia < 150) {
            distancia = 150;
        }
        else if (distancia < 100 && tipovia == "tunel" && tipovehiculo != "pesado") {
            distancia = 100;
        }
        else{
            distancia = "La distancia que sea si no es ninguno de los casos anteriores"
        }

        if (tipocalzada == "mojada") {
            distancia = distancia * 2;
        }

        capa.innerHTML = "Distancia mínima: " + distancia + " m.<br> Tipo de calzada: " + tipocalzada + "<br> Con un vehículo: " + tipovehiculo + "<br> Tipo de vía: " + tipovia;
    }

</script>
```